# Why is my European computer not working in Canada?

Tags: power-supply, europe

I built a computer in Europe and took in with me on a flight to Canada as a check-in baggage.

I bought new power cables but the computer doesn't seem to turn on at all. Only the monitor works.

Why is my computer not working? My PSU is a [THERMALTAKE PSU - Smart RGB - 600W - Certified 80PLUS](https://www.cdiscount.com/informatique/alimentation-pc/thermaltake-alimentation-pc-smart-rgb-600w-c/f-107751426-the4711246870468.html).

Comment: Does your PSU have a voltage switch?

Comment: No, but I though that new psu would automatically switch voltage

Comment: I believe they do....or should....if they don't have the manual switch. Are you sure the PSU switch is flipped to the on position, and that the cables on the board and PSU are fully plugged in? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Note: [the specification](https://www.thermaltake.com/smart-rgb-600w.html#additional) says `INPUT FREQUENCY RANGE 50 Hz - 60 Hz` and `INPUT VOLTAGE 100Vac - 240Vac`. If it's your PSU model then in theory it should work.

Comment: Link says 230V, not multi-voltage. Picture doesn't show the important side where any switch might be.

Comment: You appear to need a converter (240V to 120V) or a different power supply.

Comment: @John careful with the wording there. They need to upsample the power, not downsample. 120V to 240V is what they need.

Comment: certainly not 240 to 120… 120 to 240 might work though ;-) Google "step up transformer 120v 240v"

Answer (score 4):

This PSU should work fine as it can support 100v-240v (auto ranging) according to its specs.

It would seem more likely that something has come loose in transit. Open up the box and try reseating the connectors and memory.

Comment: Everything looks plugged in, I don't know what could be wrong. Also, the graphics card looks a little bit bent, not sure if it's related but it wasn't like this before.

Answer (score 3):

Your PSU needs 230V input, Canada is 110V

Answer (score 3):

Before getting a different PSU or converter check the back of the one you have.

According to manufacturers [specs](https://www.thermaltake.com/smart-rgb-600w.html#additional) it supports 100 - 240Vac (as mentioned by @KamilMaciorowski in comments).  I'd trust the manufacturers over the retailers description which says 230V.

The back also shows this same information in the `AC INPUT`
 box so should be easy to confirm.
[image: Back]

Comment: The specs are the same. How can I know what went wrong with the computer?

Comment: I'd follow the advice of @davidgo in their answer.  If the power supply is compatible with 110V (which it seems to be) then check cables/connections etc.  Something has either been disconnected or has broken.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to buy a transformer for 110 volts to 220 volts and branch it between
the mains and the computer,

You may find one that fits your needs
[on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=transformer+110+to+220+volt&crid=5BW9QX49GEDO&sprefix=transformer+110%2Caps%2C212&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_15).